# Configuring NetBeans 7.1.2 with remote xdebug. Client: OSX 10.7 Remote: server 2003 SP2

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, remote-debugging, netbeans-7

My problem, as the title states, is that i can not get NetBeans to connect to a remote debug session. My setup is as follows:

Client with netbeans:
Mac OSX 10.7
Netbeans 7.1.2
firewall disabled

Server with WAMP:
WAMP version 2.2
Server 2003 SP2
Firewall disabled

php.ini:
    zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll

```
[xdebug]  
xdebug.remote_enable=1  
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp  
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1  
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

When i look at PHPInfo it states that:
"This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine: Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies with Xdebug v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans"

But i see no other entry for xdebug. (acording to http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug i should see another xdebug section?)

When i run the "xdebug.org Tailored Installation Instructions" i get:

Tailored Installation Instructions
Summary
Xdebug installed: 2.2.0
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.3.10
Zend API nr: 220090626
PHP API nr: 20090626
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\WINDOWS
Configuration File: C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini
Extensions directory: c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.10\ext
You're already running the latest Xdebug version
But here are the instructions anyway

At this point, any suggestions are welcome. I'm not sure what else to try. As you can see from the phpini i have xdebug.remote_connect_back enabled - which i know can be a security issue, but should simplify setup. I have also ran the php script suggested here: https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/howto_check_xdebug_installation, and it just sits with no output.

Thanks in advance,

James.

Answer (score 0):

**Checklist:**

- Did you restart (stop - wait - start) your apache server?
- Did you configure the "Project URL" in "Run configuration" to a page that executes php?
- Does the server's firewall allow access to port 9000?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should try out Codebug http://codebugapp.com Xdebug client for OSX